# Clarification on assigning hexadecimal constant to a variable of type `signed`

Tags: c, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I am reading Jans Gustedt's "Modern C". In a discussion about how the types for numerical literals are determined, he writes about the common pitfall of assigning `0xFFFFFFFF` to a `signed` variable:

> A common error is to try to assign a hexadecimal constant to a signed with the expectation that it will represent a negative value. Consider a declaration such as int x =
> 0xFFFFFFFF. This is done under the assumption that the hexadecimal value has the same
> binary representation as the signed value −1. **On most architectures with 32-bit signed,
> this will be true (but not on all of them); but then nothing guarantees that the effective value +4294967295 is converted to the value −1**.

I want to clarify the meaning of the bolded statement. Does the statement merely state that

- The simple fact that not all architectures have 32-bit signed integers implicitly means nothing guarantees the conversion from +4294967295 to -1?

Or, is it trying to make the point that

- Even on architectures with 32-bit signed, nothing guarantees that the effective value +4294967295 is converted to -1?

If the latter, why would this be? Wouldn't the fact that the hexadecimal value has the same bit representation as -1 on architectures with 32-bit signed guarantee that the conversion will succeed there?

Comment: It's not about the size of the variable, but the rules for conversion of `unsigned` to `signed`. *Wouldn't the fact that the hexadecimal value has the same bit representation as -1 on architectures with 32-bit signed guarantee that the conversion will succeed there?* That is not guaranteed, but I think C23 brings in mandatory 2's complement representation. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69520068/4142924).

Comment: @Telescope, "... discussion about how the types for numerical literals" --> better framed as "... for numerical constants".  C defines 0xFFFFFFFF and  4294967295 as _integer constants_.  C uses _literal_ for _string literals_ and _compound literals_.

Comment: This is mostly there for completeness. In 1989, some not overly competent people in the standard committee made a push saying something along the lines of that the C standard wasn't allowed to favour some existing technology over another. And so they allowed 1's complement and signed magnitude as signed formats. This huge design mistake has been cluttering up the C language ever since, finally to be corrected in C23 where support for exotic/fictional computers is finally removed. The general recommendation, C23 or not, is to focus on coding C for computers existing in the real world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it trying to make the point that
>
> - Even on architectures with 32-bit signed, nothing guarantees that the effective value +4294967295 is converted to -1?

^ This.

If the type of `0xffffffff` is unsigned, as stipulated, then assignment to an object of type [`signed`] `int` induces a conversion to that type. The language spec says:

> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `bool`, if the value
> can be represented by the new type, [...].
> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, [...]
> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; **either the result is
> implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.**

(C23 6.3.1.3)

The spec allows for a signal to be raised instead of the conversion proceeding, and if no signal is raised then then the result of the conversion is up to the implementation. The common error Gustedt describes amounts to assuming that the bit pattern of the unsigned value will be reinterpreted as a that of a signed `int`.  Some implementations in fact do that, but they are not required to do, and there are other plausible alternatives.  For instance, out of range values might be converted to an extreme value of the destination type.

Answer (score 0):

> why would this be

Because the C standard doesn't give a guarantee, so you don't have it.

> Wouldn't the fact that the hexadecimal value has the same bit representation as -1 on architectures with 32-bit signed guarantee

None of this matters. The C standard has decided not to guarantee anything about this conversion, and this fact overrides everything else. Even if the hardware is perfectly suited to make the conversion just as you expect it, you cannot rely on it, because the implementation can detect that the conversion result is not guaranteed to be anything in particular and use this fact to e.g. optimise the conversion out of existence completely.

Comment: Re “The C standard has decided not to guarantee anything about this conversion”: The C standard guarantees two things about this conversion: One, there is an `int` result or there is a signal. Two, the implementation must document the `int` result or the signal. Re “the implementation can detect that the conversion result is not guaranteed to be anything in particular and use this fact to e.g. optimise the conversion out of existence completely”: No, it cannot optimize the conversion away. It must provide the `int` result or the signal specified in the implementation’s documentation.

Comment: Re “this fact overrides everything else”: No, when the C standard says something is undefined, that overrides **only** everything else **in the standard**. It does not override anything outside the standard, such as laws about consumer product safety or documentation of the compiler or the operating system.